# Save converted binary code in local storage of browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

I have a php file "linkToThePhpFileHere.php". It creates a QR Code and returns something like that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7zHA.png

That's how I display the code:

```
<div style="background-image: url(linkToThePhpFileHere.php);"></div>
```

But I want to store the content of "linkToThePhpFileHere.php" in an array in the local storage of the browser and I think, it's not a good idea to save the binary code there?

Is it possible to use `Javascript/Jquery` to load and convert the cotent of my file. It should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/soYPr.png and be saved in a var:

```
var str = convertToSth($.get("linkToThePhpFileHere.php"));
```

Comment: as long as the image is under 5mb as base64, no problem; where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = convertToSth($.get("linkToThePhpFileHere.php"));//this should be in base64
localStorage.setItem("imgData", str );
```

```js
function getBase64Image(img) {

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
  }

  function getImage(imageUrl, callback) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    img.src = imageUrl;
    img.onload = function() {
      var str = getBase64Image(img);
      if (typeof callback == "function") callback(str);

    }
  }

getImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg',function(imgData){
localStorage.setItem("imgData1", str );
})

getImage('linkToThePhpFileHere.php',function(imgData){
localStorage.setItem("imgData1", str );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store `data URI` representation of image in `localStorage`

```
  window.onload = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("image") === null) {
      fetch("linkToThePhpFileHere.php")
      .then(response => reponse.blob())
      .then(blob => {         
        const reader = new FileReader;
        reader.onload = () {
          localStorage.setItem("image", reader.result);
          document.querySelector("div")
          .style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ");";
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
      })
    } else {
      document.querySelector("div")
      .style.backgroundImage = "url(" + localStorage.getImage("image") + ")";
    }
  }
```